# inserting values from array in excel file through PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to create an excel file with values which I get from the following array

```
for ($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){

for ($j=16;$j<=24;$j++){
    $data1=array($R,$C,$i,$j,'0','0'); .
```

I tried to do something like that

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    $data1
);
```

using an existing example.However,each time I try to run this php file, excel stops working.What should I try?

edit

```
$R=1;
$C=0.7;


for ($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){

for ($j=16;$j<=24;$j++){
    $data1[]=array($R,$C,$i,$j,'0','0');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        $data1)

);

    }}
```

Comment: You should try some basic debugging, perhaps var dumping $data1 so we can see what it actually contains

Comment: array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  float(0.7)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  int(16)
  [4]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  float(0.7)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  int(17)
  [4]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "0"
} 

and so on...

Comment: And do you mean that MS Excel stops working when you try to load the generated file? or that PHPExcel stops working? Is a file generated or not? Are there any error messages, whether displayed on screen or written to log files?

Comment: Yes, there is a file generated. When I try to open this specific file, the MS Excel stops working.This is the displayed error message : There was a problem sending the command to the program.

Comment: So show a bit more code, like the save, perhaps you're doing something wrong there

Comment: I used example 33chartcreate-column-2.php and i only changed these lines : require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';


$R=1;
$C=0.7;


for ($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){
 
for ($j=16;$j<=24;$j++){
 $data1=array($R,$C,$i,$j,'0','0');
  
 
 }}
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
 $data1
);

Comment: Well that certainly won't create a broken file, simply one containing garbage data (I've just run it myself to test).... what version of MS Excel are you using?

Comment: Note that `$data1` probably isn't what you believe it to be, but even that doesn't break the generated file, just renders the chart meaningless

Comment: I use excel 2007.I tried to do the same think with 33chartcreate-column.php and it worked,however it created a file with only 1 row, containing only the values from the last loop.

Comment: Like I said, `$data` doesn't contain what you expect..... `$data1[]=array($R,$C,$i,$j,'0','0');` is probably what you meant

Comment: It gives warnings like this Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\family_guy\codecall\Classes\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell\DefaultValueBinder.php on line 95

Warning: mb_substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\family_guy\codecall\Classes\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\String.php on line 575

Comment: EDIT THE REAL CODE THAT YOU'RE USING INTO YOUR QUESTION

Comment: But stop trying to instantiate new PHPExcel objects in your loops; stop casting arrays to arrays..... I've tried to show you how to do this..... but your issue seems to be with basic PHP, perhaps you should try doing a few simple projects so that you understand how arrays work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$R=1; 
$C=0.7; 
for ($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){ 
    for ($j=16;$j<=24;$j++){ 
        $data1[]=array($R,$C,$i,$j,'0','0'); 
    }
}
$objWorksheet->fromArray( $data1 );

//  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesLabels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1),   //  'Budget'
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$1', NULL, 1),   //  'Forecast'
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$E$1', NULL, 1),   //  'Actual'
);
//  Set the X-Axis Labels
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$B$13', NULL, 12),    //  Q1 to Q4 for 2010 to 2012
);
//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$13', NULL, 12),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$13', NULL, 12),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$E$2:$E$13', NULL, 12),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
);
//  Set additional dataseries parameters
//      Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotArea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_BOTTOM, NULL, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Grouped Column Chart');
$xAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Financial Period');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');


//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotArea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    $xAxisLabel,    // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('G2');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('P20');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);


// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Comment: I see.That worked.Thanks a lot for your help and my apologies for wasting your time.It's my first time using PHPExcel  and I had some problems with learning how to use it.